# Pointer assignment in python is changing the reference pointer list

Tags: python, linked-list

I was doing a code of rotating the linked list given the rotation amount on leetcode. I came across interesting problem.

Problem:  After assigning the head (H) of the linked list to some other pointer (P) and then rotating the pointer P would make the next element of header pointer H to null.

Example:

## If you pass any linked list header to function you can easily reproduce this

## My purpose is not to traverse the list. I just wants to understand why does the reference of that pointer change and remains only first value of the listed gets printed?

```
def rotateRight(self, head: Optional[ListNode], k: int) -> Optional[ListNode]:
    dummy = head # Pointer pointing to the head of the linked list
    pre = None
    # Traversing the dummy pointer and keeping backward link to pre pointer
    while dummy:
        nex = dummy.next
        dummy.next = pre
        pre = dummy
        dummy = nex
    while head:
        print(head.val) # This would print only the head of the linked list which is 1 in my example of 1,2,3,4,5 it seems like its next is pointing to null
        head = head.next
```

Pass value of the reference pointing elements 1,2,3,4,5 and my head reference would only print the first element of the list
Could anyone please explain the reason for this?

Comment: Since you are using the word "pointer" so many times in throughout the question, I'd point out that all of these are references, not pointers

Comment: Right.  After your first statement. `dummy` and `head` both reference the same object.  That does not make a copy.  When you change `dummy`, you also change `head`.  You don't need to change the object to traverse the list.

Comment: Python does not have pointers. Python has *names*. They are just "labels" that you attach to objects. The label can be easily moved from object to object and an object can have many labels.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify any link node to traverse the list.

```
def rotateRight(self, head: Optional[ListNode], k: int) -> Optional[ListNode]:
    dummy = head
    pre = None
    while dummy:
        nex = dummy.next
        pre = dummy
        dummy = nex
    while head:
        print(head.val) # This would print only the head of the linked list         
        head = head.next
```

Or, even simpler:

```
    while dummy:
        pre, dummy = dummy, dummy.next
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but I do understand that though my purpose is not to reverse the linked list but I want to know the behavior of python referencing. I have updated my question please feel free to comment on that